# AsyncTask does not execute with Android 4.0 and higher

Tags: android

I have an application based on multiple extends of AsyncTask class.

Everything works fine with any Android version under 4.0.

With 4.0 or higher none of my "doInBackground" methods execute. OnPreExecute is called but "doInBackground" and onPostExecute never get reached.

I read that this is a google problem. Is there any way to fix this? I need to keep the AsyncTasks classes and behavior. Using normal threads means that i need to change my entire app.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why my question was downvoted because this is indeed a Google compatibility problem between android versions.

I've used the following helper class to execute asynk tasks:

```
   public class AsyncTaskExecutionHelper {
static class HoneycombExecutionHelper {
    public static <P> void execute(AsyncTask<P, ?, ?> asyncTask, boolean parallel, P... params) {
        Executor executor = parallel ? AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR : AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR;
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(executor, params);
    }
}

public static <P> void executeParallel(AsyncTask<P, ?, ?> asyncTask, P... params) {
    execute(asyncTask, true, params);
}

public static <P> void executeSerial(AsyncTask<P, ?, ?> asyncTask, P... params) {
    execute(asyncTask, false, params);
}

private static <P> void execute(AsyncTask<P, ?, ?> asyncTask, boolean parallel, P... params) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        HoneycombExecutionHelper.execute(asyncTask, parallel, params);
    } else {
        asyncTask.execute(params);
    }
}
```

}

Call your asynk tasks in the following way:

```
       CustomAsynkTas customTask = new CustomAsynkTask();
       AsyncTaskExecutionHelper.executeParallel(customTask);
```

where

```
CustomAsynkTask extends AsyncTask 
{
      //etc
 }
```

Tested and it works on all android versions.

Comment: How can it work on all android versions, when THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR was first introduced in 3.0???

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that non of your AsyncTask doesn't work, if you running a lot of them at the startup and they are executing in single thread it may take a while to execute all of them.

Try to run a new one AsyncTask in the your Application.onCreate or main activity onCreate and see if it runs. This way you will test an independent AsyncTask which starts at very beginning.